# Links added in "Quick Links" webpart to force download the documents works only when double clicks

Tags: sharepoint-online, document, word, quick-links

**Force downloading** the word documents stored in SharePoint when the user clicks on the link (*using "**Quick Links**" webpart*) is not working as expected.

To successfully download the file, the link **required to be clicked twice**!!.

I've added the links in "Quick Links" webpart in the below format

```
https://TenantName.sharepoint.com/:w:/s/SiteCollectionName/EV8bwK_6d9hKou_RVS7GFXcBlMWrv5nZpViNQmUHtwarJA?e=3RPjsi&download=1
```

[image]

The query string parameter **&download=1** is used to force download the document as I don't want them to be opened in Word Online.

[image: quick links setup]

When I click on my Quick Links, it takes 2 clicks to trigger the download. On the first click, the browsers address bar updates but nothing is downloaded. The second click works. (*Please test it by adding multiple links of different files to the webpart, as it is working correctly during the first link click but misbehaving for the subsequent file download links*)

Using a Text Web Part and simple hyperlinks works fine, but doesn't look as good.

Has anyone been able to one click download SharePoint Hosted Word documents using quick links?

Comment: This doesn't work for me on the latest Edge either. Interestingly, the first time I click on a link it does trigger download, but further clicks (on different links) does not. Did you try with multiple links?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/857446/links-added-in-34quick-links34-webpart-to-force-do.html

Answer (score 2):

### You can't out-of-the-box:

The Quick Links web part does NOT allow for one-click download functionality.

It seems that SharePoint handles tenant-based download links differently than **out-of-tenant** links.

Ex, you can have multiple out-of-tenant based links in Quick Links and one click will always trigger the action of the link. However, if you use tenant-based download links with `&download=1` or `download.aspx`, you need to double-click the link to trigger the download.

### Workaround:

1. Instead of using `&download=1`, you can build a download link by utilizing the `download.aspx` page with a `UniqueId` parameter:

> Get the `UniqueId` for your target file by opening the file in Word Online (through SharePoint). The URL of the page should look like this:
>
> ```
> https://yourtenant.sharepoint.com/:w:/r/sites/yoursite/_layouts/15/Doc.aspx?sourcedoc=%7B91EA3429-A536-4894-B3D9-FAB385EDC188%7D&file=Test-File-1.docx&action=default&mobileredirect=true
> ```
>
> Extract the `sourcedoc` query string without the leading `%7B` and without the trailing `%7D`:
> `91EA3429-A536-4894-B3D9-FAB385EDC188`
>
> Now you can build the download link:
>
> ```
> https://yourtenant.sharepoint.com/sites/yoursite/_layouts/15/download.aspx?UniqueId={91EA3429-A536-4894-B3D9-FAB385EDC188}
> ```

2. Use a site like [bitly.com](https://bit.ly.com) to generate an **out-of-tenant** redirect/shortened link:

> [image: Bit.ly generating a short link redirect]
>
> Add the redirect/shortened link to your Quick Links web part:
> [image: A GIF of the Quick Links web part be able to download files with one click!]

Comment: @dan-walters, ^ is this what you were hoping for? @

Comment: Could you please try it with multiple document links?

Comment: @TerminalVelocity yes, but does this work with multiple different document links. Add documents to Link2 and Link3, then this will fail.

Comment: @DanWalters I have updated my answer to include a workaround for multiple document links! Check it out!

Comment: @TerminalVelocity thanks for the workaround. as of today, bitly free account allows unlimited clicks for 50 links, which is enough for my application. bounty awarded

Answer (score 0):

Your link can be in the following format for it to be easily downloaded in one click.

https://yourtenant.sharepoint.com/sites/yoursite/Document-Library/Folder/File-Name.docx

To easily get the url in this format, you may open the file in Desktop App:

1. On SharePoint, right-click file name
2. Open > Open in app
3. File > Info > Copy Path
4. Remove the "?web=1" at the end of the link
5. Use this link the the Quick Links part

Comment: thanks, but I already have links hat download in one click. This format doesn't help. It is the web-part that i'm having trouble with.

Comment: additionally, the quick link web-part will append the web view parameter to this link type anyway.